# How to show the horizontal List of items using Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P8Ou.png)

I am trying to show the list of categories using Flatlist but not getting the desired results. I have attached an image for ReferenceError.

I have used position absolute and `zindex` to the `flatlist` render item but unable to get the list as i want.

Please have a look to the attached screenshot.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you provide some piece of your code please? A replication through Codesandbox would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please have a look to the attached screenshot once because i have just added render item to show the elements of an array. It is showing a horizontal list but i want to display it like the screenshot

Comment: <FlatList
        data={ItemsData}
        horizontal
        renderItem={renderCategoryItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
        contentContainerStyle={{marginHorizontal: 10, marginTop: 10}}
      />

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.